# Consuming a web service and auto populate textbox by the given xml data after clicking a button in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

i have textbox where a voter id will be given as an input,besides that there is "show information" button. After clicking that textbox of "name","address","age" will be populated. the information is to be retrieved from http://nerdcastlebd.com/web_service/voterdb/index.php/voters/voter/9509623450915. Last slash has the voter id. I have  been through many resources but cant get a hold of them. i am new in mvc. Plz help

```
               <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.patient.voter_id,"Voter Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.patient.voter_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.patient.voter_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Voter Information" id="btnVoter" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.patient.name,"Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.patient.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.patient.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.patient.age,"Age", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.patient.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.patient.age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.patient.address,"Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.patient.address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.patient.address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What you have tried to do? Where you are stuck? Can you add the code you experimented?

Comment: i have tried to add server reference but it is not taking it.shows error..i am not getting any idea how to start..sample code will be very much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on **client side** (View) with `jQuery` and the flow will look similar to the one i described below.

1) Attach `.click()` event to `button` to *call the service* and *populate* the fields when is pressed.

2) Get the `id` and **concatenate** to *base* `url`. With this make a `GET` call to take data from service.

3) After you get data from service you can populate your fields.

```
$('#btnVoter').click(function(){
    var id = $('#voterId').val();
    $.get('http://nerdcastlebd.com/web_service/voterdb/index.php/voters/voter/' + id, function(data, status) {
        $('#voterName').val(data.name);
        // populate other (address, age) data on page
    });
});
```

**Notes:** The `ids` i used may **not match** your inputs `id` on page, please update them accordingly.

Comment: i have edited my question..this is my view..how to write code for ur first 3 instructions?plz reply.the deadline is 2morrow

Comment: @star_tasneem `btnVoter` should be `type='button`. To take other fields `id`, inspect page with developer tools and take voter id, and other fields id you need.

Comment: inside click function add `event.preventDefault()` if you keep `type='submit'`. Instead of `#voterId` i think you have `#patient_voter_id` and so on.

Comment: <script>
        $('#btnVoter').click(function () {
            var id = $('#patient_voter_id').val();
            $.get('http://nerdcastlebd.com/web_service/voterdb/index.php/voters/voter/' + id, function (data, status) {
                $('#patient_name').val(data.patient_name);
            });
        });
    </script>

i have written that..but it's not working and i have used button type

Comment: @star_tasneem change with `$('#patient_name').val(data.name);`, also it's cood to put an `console.log(data);` to be sure what data contains.

Comment: @star_tasneem you should press F12 to see the errors in console and what it display on `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://nerdcastlebd.com/web_service/voterdb/index.php/voters/voter/5644309456813. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. This is the error shown in the console

Comment: @star_tasneem the problem is from the server, [see this](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/01/18/getting-cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-complex-jquery-ajax-requests/) they didn't configure the server to allow the data to be taken from outside the domain, see the link i provided for more.